# Counting elements based on placement in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7

Below, I have a table where columns `TST1` to `TST5` can take no values or one of the following: `NOT_DONE` `INCOMP` `UNTESTED` `30` `35` `40` `45` `50`

I need to count the number of elements (rows) that are validated from the table below.

An element is considered **validated** when the right-most value is one between 30 and 50 (seperated by 5, so 30, 35, 40...). This means that if the row has no value for all `TST1` to `TST5` then nothing is counted. If a numerical value is found to the left of either `NOT_DONE` `INCOMP` or `UNTESTED` then it is not validated.

In other words, I need to count each row right to left.

For example from the table below, only 6 elements are considered validated.

Finally, I need to count how many of these belong to group A or B.

My initial idea to solve this was to create a new column with all the validated elements but I'm really not sure how to do this.

I am using python 2.7 and pandas 0.24.2. I am new to this, any help or guidance is greatly appreciated.

```
+-------+----------+----------+----------+--------+----------+
| Group | TST1     | TST2     | TST3     | TST4   | TST5     |
+-------+----------+----------+----------+--------+----------+
| A     |          | NOT_DONE |          |        | 50       |
+-------+----------+----------+----------+--------+----------+
| A     |          |          | 35       |        |          |
+-------+----------+----------+----------+--------+----------+
| B     |          |          |          |        |          |
+-------+----------+----------+----------+--------+----------+
| A     |          |          | INCOMP   |        |          |
+-------+----------+----------+----------+--------+----------+
| B     | UNTESTED |          | 50       | INCOMP |          |
+-------+----------+----------+----------+--------+----------+
| B     |          |          |          |        |          |
+-------+----------+----------+----------+--------+----------+
| B     |          | 30       |          |        |          |
+-------+----------+----------+----------+--------+----------+
| A     |          | INCOMP   | 40       |        |          |
+-------+----------+----------+----------+--------+----------+
| B     |          |          |          |        | UNTESTED |
+-------+----------+----------+----------+--------+----------+
| A     |          |          |          |        |          |
+-------+----------+----------+----------+--------+----------+
| B     |          | INCOMP   |          |        |          |
+-------+----------+----------+----------+--------+----------+
| A     |          |          |          |        |          |
+-------+----------+----------+----------+--------+----------+
| B     |          | 50       |          |        |          |
+-------+----------+----------+----------+--------+----------+
| B     |          |          | UNTESTED | 35     | NOT_DONE |
+-------+----------+----------+----------+--------+----------+
| B     |          |          |          |        |          |
+-------+----------+----------+----------+--------+----------+
| A     |          | 40       |          | INCOMP |          |
+-------+----------+----------+----------+--------+----------+
| A     |          |          |          | 30     |          |
+-------+----------+----------+----------+--------+----------+
| B     |          |          |          |        |          |
+-------+----------+----------+----------+--------+----------+
| B     |          | NOT_DONE |          | 30     | NOT_DONE |
+-------+----------+----------+----------+--------+----------+
```

**Edit:**
This is what I have tried but it counts all rows presenting a numerical value, not the ones with right-most value being numerical. I really have no idea on how to select going from the right first.

```
    filter1 = df.loc[:, 'TST1':'TST5']\
        .apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).str.match(r'\d+\.*\d*'), axis=0)\
        .any(axis=1)
    number_validated = filter1.sum()
    print "Number of validated items: ", number_validated
```

Expected output should just be a short textual summary:

```
Number of validated items: 5
Number of group A validated items: 4
Number of group B validated items: 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option, tested on python 2.7.18 and pandas 0.24.2 (though it works fine in python 3):

1. Use [`ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html) to extract the rightmost values and [`to_numeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) to coerce them into numbers:

   ```py
   rightmost = df.filter(like='TST').ffill(axis='columns').iloc[:, -1]
   rightmost = pd.to_numeric(rightmost, errors='coerce')

   # 0      NaN
   # 1     35.0
   # 2      NaN
   # 3      NaN
   # 4      NaN
   # 5      NaN
   # 6     30.0
   # 7     40.0
   # 8      NaN
   # 9      NaN
   # 10     NaN
   # 11     NaN
   # 12    50.0
   # 13     NaN
   # 14     NaN
   # 15     NaN
   # 16    30.0
   # 17     NaN
   # 18     NaN
   # Name: TST5, dtype: float64
   ```
2. Then [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) the `Group` and check if they are [`between`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html) 30 and 50 (inclusive):

   ```py
   valid = rightmost.groupby(df.Group).apply(
       lambda g: g.between(30, 50, inclusive='both').sum()
   ).to_frame('Valid')

   #        Valid
   # Group       
   # A          3
   # B          2
   ```